# R: Scrape some info from an HTML

Tags: r, rvest

I have a HTML file that follows this format:

`<div id='1' class='location element' style='width:100px; top:5068px; left: 3332px;'><div class='position'></div><div class='time'></div><div class='age'></div>Name</div>`

And I would like to retrieve the string from the first `div` (in this case `location') and the name.

So far, I can retrieve the name using the id number.

```
html_file%>% 
  html_nodes("#1") %>%
  html_text()
```

How can I retrieve the first field 'class'?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `html_attr`:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
html_file%>% 
    html_nodes("#1") %>%
    html_attr("class")

[1] "location element"
```

NB: if you use `html_attrs()` you can get all attributes out and can go from there too:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
html_file%>% 
    html_nodes("#1") %>%
    html_attrs()

[[1]]
                                      id                                    class 
                                     "1"                       "location element" 
                                   style 
"width:100px; top:5068px; left: 3332px;"
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. Quick question, is there a way to return both the name and the class attribute using one instruction? Or do I have to use `html_nodes('#1') %>% html_attr('class')` and `html_nodes('#1') %>% html_text()'`

Comment: I think you'll need both (or do `x< - html_file %>% html_nodes('#1')` and then do `html_text(x)` and `html_attr(x, 'class')`)

Comment: Got it! Thanks Jeremy.